# Reload Page Only Once In IONIC 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, page-refresh

I need to reload my page only once
Here is what i tried so far...

- like using `location.reload();` but it Goes in a loop and keeps on reloading .
- then I tried setting a Storage Variable.

  `storage.set('reload_flag',false);`

in Constructor of traget Page I wrote This Line

```
`storage.get('reload_flag').then((val) => {
        if (!val) {
            // do Nothing
        }
    else{
        location.reload();
    }});`
```

But the Results are not as expected (the Constructor part is not working).

- but if i used on-Refresher it will work but its not the appropriate way

  `doRefresh(refresher) {
      console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);
          location.reload(); // Reloadin The Page 
     setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Async operation has ended');
        refresher.complete();
      }, 2000);
    }`

Comment: Is "flase" a spelling mistake in your code or just in your question?

Comment: not workink even after changing the spelling

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(this.navCtrl.getActive().component);
```

Comment: where to add this line exactly